# Android: Refresh ArrayAdapter on resume

Tags: android, refresh

I am trying to create a refesh function for my main page. I have searched many site but i can't seem to find a (for me) acccesseble exaple. I am loading information from a sQLLite database. When i use my add activity and i return to the MainScreen activity the item i have added do not appear. How could i refresh this data the moment de activity is resumed.

Any help is welcome, thx in advance.

```
      public ListView whiskeylist;
      String[] DataArryWhiskey;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Start db view of whiskey
    DBConfig info = new DBConfig(this);

    info.open();
        DataArryWhiskey = info.getDataInArray();
    info.close();


    whiskeylist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listofWhiskey);
    whiskeylist.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    whiskeylist.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, DataArryWhiskey));


}// end onCreate
```

On The advice of Adil i change the code to

```
      public ListView whiskeylist;
String[] DataArryWhiskey;
ListAdapter Adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 

    // Start db view of whiskey 
    DBConfig info = new DBConfig(this); 

    info.open(); 
         DataArryWhiskey = info.getDataInArray(); 
    info.close(); 


    whiskeylist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listofWhiskey); 
    Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, DataArryWhiskey); 
    whiskeylist.setAdapter(Adapter); 

    // End db view of whiskey


}// end onCreate

@Override
public void onResume() 
{ 
    super.onResume(); 
    DBConfig info = new DBConfig(this); 

    info.open(); 
        DataArryWhiskey = info.getDataInArray(); 
    info.close(); 
    Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  // refresh adapter     
}
```

however i get a error on notifyDataSetChanged "the method notifyDataSetChanged is undefined for the type ListAdapter" <- fixed it by changing the ListAdapter to ArrayAdapter but the app still crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//made changes in your oncreate method, see below

```
DBConfig info;
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

// Start db view of whiskey
info = new DBConfig(this);
whiskeylist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listofWhiskey);
whiskeylist.setOnItemClickListener(this);
 }// end onCreate
```

another method give below, call this method from on ActivityResult(), but before doing that ensure that
the field you added with another activity also saved into database.
call show Data() from onActivityResult method or from onResume()

```
private void showData()
{
  info.open();
    DataArryWhiskey = info.getDataInArray();
info.close();
 whiskeylist.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, DataArryWhiskey));
}
```

Comment: one question, how you are starting your add activity??
Two step.. if you are starting your add Activty through startActivityForResult.
1) call showData() from onActivityResult method
2) or just call this method from onResume()

Comment: setting another adapter is bad approach. you should refresh the old adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Get a class level variable of `ArrayAdapter adapter;` and initialize it like this way:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, DataArryWhiskey);
hiskeylist.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and inside `onResume()` do like this way.

```
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    info.open();
    DataArryWhiskey = info.getDataInArray();
    info.close();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  // refresh adapter    
}
```

**My Recommendation:**
Since you are getting your values from database, use [`SimpleCursorAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) instead of `ArrayAdapter`. which will do lots of other work also for you.

[Here is a tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) how to use `SimpleCursorAdapter`

Comment: i get a error on notifyDataSetChanged "the method notifyDataSetChanged is undefined for the type ListAdapter" see original question for code

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `adapter.clear();` before adding items.